# YouTube Season/Episode presentation

Tags: youtube

I found the following for a YouTube video, that I had never seen before:

[image: example]

As you can see, it say's the name of the channel followed by the season and the episode. I was wondering how this was done and whether I could set that up on my channel (it would make a lot of sense for me).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are referring to is called a ***series playlist***. A series playlist is used to display videos in that manner.

What you have misunderstood is that it's actually the name of the show that is displayed before the "S11 E80", although I understand that it is confusing when the show has the same name as the channel.

This feature is easily utilized, it is however required that you have a verified channel. If you do, you should easily be able to add a series playlist from the playlist menu in the Youtube studio.

Best of luck

Answer (score 1):

No, they did not misunderstand anything. There's actually a difference between what the OP observed and shared and the series playlist feature you're talking about. The former is possible through a series editor tool that is not yet available to everyone - it's in beta and has been, reportedly, available on YouTube Red. https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/IBMNlSLSCJ8

Comment: Welcome! Since SE isn't a forum, there is no guarantee that your answer will always be displayed in a way that makes sense to see the context of the accepted answer. Can you rephrase your answer so that it can stand alone?

Comment: Ah, interesting. I know that one can mark videos as part of a playlist, and I presumed that YT would automatically figure out season and episode numbers. But apparently there is a dedicated tool for that. Thanks.

Comment: And it looks like the feature was eventually discontinued in August 2019: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7124330